# Unable to export MongoDB database from a remote server

Tags: mongodb

> mongoexport --host=hostname --port=27017 --db=dbname --collection=
>   collection_name --out=path/data.json

Here is the error which I'm getting

> error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Comment: Perhaps you should check if the server `hostname` is reachable by doing a ping. I suspect that you need to replace "hostname" with a real `hostname` or "ip address".

Answer (score 0):

you need to fill a remote hostname or a remote ip, username and password if required.

```
mongoexport --host hostname --port 27017 --username user --password "pass" --collection collectionName --out=path/data.json
```

try read the [official mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Comment: I have entered everything which is required but it's still giving me that error